# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2-3n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}-4n^2}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series converge or diverge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n^2-3n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}-4n^2}}$$

I have tried using the comparison test, however when simplifying this i get $1/\sqrt[3]n$.
I do not know what to compare with, I have tried comparing with something related with the p-test but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the series converge.

Comment: Yes, thanks, badly (wrongly) put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{n^2-3n}{(n^{10}-4n^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\sim_{+\infty}\frac{n^2}{n^{10\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{n^2}{n^{15}}=\frac{1}{n^{\frac{4}{3}}}$ hence the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n^2-3n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}-4n^2}}\sim\frac{n^2}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}}}=\frac{n^2}{n^{10/3}}=\frac1{n^{4/3}}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$
n^2-3n\sim n^2
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[3]{n^{10}-4n^2}\sim n^{10/3},
$$
where $\sim$ denotes that the ratio of the two sides goes to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.
Hence,
$$
\frac{n^2-3n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}-4n^2}}\sim n^{-4/3}
$$
and the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for $n$ large enough, we have the following inequality 
$$0<\frac{n^2-3n}{\sqrt[3]{n^{10}-4n^2}}<\frac{n^2}{n^{\frac{10}{3}}\sqrt[3]{1-4/n^{8}}}<\frac{n^2}{n^{\frac{10}{3}}\sqrt[3]{1/2}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{n^{\frac{4}{3}}}.$$
That could help.